# Switching the migration order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails newbie here.
I generated a Post scaffold so that users can post stuff.
But when I try to create a new post, the description box comes up first.

```
New Post



Description

Title




Back
```

I want users to be able to input the title first before the description. I believe this is happening because in my migration file, I have this.

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.text :description
      t.string :title
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

How would I switch between the description and the title?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Your migration file don't have anything to do with the order that your user inputs anything.

If you want your users to input something before another, that logic should be elsewhere.

Comment: Ah! I got it. All I had to do was to change it from the _form partial. Thanks